# Нюансы меж русским и японским

Tags: синтаксис, терминология, значение, выбор

Я ищу инфу (аналогичную той, что в книге) goyaki akuyaki no byori. [Психология ошибочных и неточных переводов. Токио], 1971. Здесь задаю вопрос, надеясь на вдруг и авось. Возможно, кто-то здесь тоже интересуется?